# Silvetlight 5 : PivotViewer: How to change PivotViewer Filter in code behind S

Tags: pivotviewer

I have extended the PivotViewer control and hid the Filter Panel. I have a TreeView with Categories. Each category have subitems under them. I would like to set the filter for the PivotViewer when a category is selected/clicked on the treeView . In TreeView_MouseLeftButtonUp, I am doing the following

```
 private void myTreeView_MouseLeftButtonUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
 var grouping = (IGrouping<string, Web.SDKSampleCode>)myTreeView.SelectedItem;
 pViewer.Filter = string.Format("Category = EQ.{0}", grouping.Key.ToString());
}
```

I do see FilterChanged is fired, but there are two issues:
a) FilterChanged is fired twice and 
b) Filter is not applied either.

It all works with the FilterPanel , but I have to hide the FilterPanel in my app and instead use TreeView so it can act as TOC as well as for Filtering categories.

Any help is much appreciated.
SideNote, I am using SL5 + Ria services for fetching data and display in PivotViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I needed to call SetViewerState(filterstring)

```
pViewer.Filter = string.Format("facet=Category&Category=EQ.{0}", grouping.Key.ToString());
                pViewer.SetViewerState(pViewer.Filter);
```